# как добавлять элементы в масив js?

Tags: html, jquery

При вводе значения в  это значение появляется снизу но если пользователь ввел что-то другое это значение снизу заменяется на новое,как сделать так чтоб новое значение не заменяло старое значение?
вот весь код:    https://pastebin.com/nCyTE6FM

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А где массив? ..

Comment: `значени.innerHTML  += элемент куда вставляешь`

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, вы имеете ввиду что-то типа этого

```js
var data = [];
$("input[type='text']").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() !== "") {
    data.push($(this).val())
    pushResult();
  }
});

function pushResult() {
  console.log(data)
  $('#result').html('')
  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    $('#result').append(`<li key="${key}">${value}</li>`)
  });

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />

<ul id="result">

</ul>
```